# Extend repository classes in Symfony2 bundles

Tags: symfony

Say I used a third party blog bundle, and there's a `BlogRepository` class in there, I wanted to add more methods to this repository class. I tried using bundle inheritance described in the official doc, but it looks like it can't be done on entity repository classes.

The reason I figured is due to this method `$this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('MyBundle:Entity')` expects the declaration of the entity class in your own bundle.

Does anyone know how to do that? I think there must be a way to do it via DI, as adding your own methods to a repository class should be a common practice.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

very interesting.. Which bundle are you using and why it's not possible to extend it's Repository class? In my practice there was only one situation where I needed to extend third party bundle's repository class (I was using NestedTree extension from DoctrineExtensions with StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle) and I simply did it as such a way:

```
class TermRepository extends NestedTreeRepository {
...
}
```

Comment: and don't forget to put `use Path\To\NestedTreeRepository` ;-)

Comment: If you simply extends the repository class, how do you instantiate your custom class? I assume you would need to do via $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('MyBundle:Entity'), right? The problem is your custom bundle won't find the "Entity" from the parent bundle.

Answer (score 0):

Call your repository like service `->get("service.aliace")`

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stackoverflow. Please add some more description to your answer so it becomes more valuable for other users.